# Find customers that never placed an order with an employee

Tags: mysql, sql

We have the following details from the output of a query a supplier id, a category name, and product count,
so 3 columns. Each supplier holds a certain category of products, and for each
category, the third column lists the number of products in that particular category.
How to write a query using this table which returns -
supplier if, category name, prodcount*100/totalnumberofproducts
Basically it should list the % of product in that category

The initial query that give the product count for each category is:

```
SELECT s.SupplierID, s.CompanyName AS Supplier, cat.CategoryName, 
    COUNT(*) AS CatProductCount
FROM suppliers AS s
JOIN products AS p ON s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID  
JOIN categories AS cat ON p.CategoryID = cat.CategoryID 
GROUP BY s.SupplierID, s.CompanyName, cat.CategoryName;
```

**My Thoughts:**
So if the initial query is S.

We could do

```
select supplierId, sum(productCount) as total from S groupby supplierID
```

This will tell us the total number of product for each supplier.
Let this query be called S2

```
select S.supplierId, (S.productCount*100)/S2.total from S inner join S2 on S.supplierID=S2.supplierId
```

I think I have the correct idea but the exact syntax I am using will not work.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and update the question with the relevant data. It will be much easier to debug and solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use these two possibilities

As joined table

```
SELECT s.SupplierID, s.CompanyName AS Supplier, cat.CategoryName, 
    COUNT(*) * 100/ total as percentage_count
FROM suppliers AS s
JOIN products AS p ON s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID  
JOIN categories AS cat ON p.CategoryID = cat.CategoryID 
JOIN (select supplierId, sum(productCount) as total from suppliers group by supplierID ) S1 ON S1.supplierId = S,suppliers
GROUP BY s.SupplierID, s.CompanyName, cat.CategoryName;
```

Or as subselct

```
SELECT s.SupplierID, s.CompanyName AS Supplier, cat.CategoryName, 
    COUNT(*) * 100 / (select sum(productCount)  from suppliers S1 WHERE S1.suppliers  = S.supplierID ) as percentage_count
FROM suppliers AS s
JOIN products AS p ON s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID  
JOIN categories AS cat ON p.CategoryID = cat.CategoryID 
GROUP BY s.SupplierID, s.CompanyName, cat.CategoryName;
```

you should test both to see what is faster i would guess the second